# Good Xen image repository?

Tags: xen, repository, image

Does anyone know of a good image repo for Xen, sort of like Appliance store for VmWare? Also something like sourceforge but for xen, with tools and such?

I know there used to be jailbreak.org - which is not closed.

Citrix doesn't provide one or at least I don't know of one.

I may be asking for too much.. :-)

P.S.: I know I can create my own templates, but it's kind of fun to see what other people are doing. The way I find new good software is by browsing sourceforge and freshmeat, so kinds of wondering if there is something for Xen.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jailtime.org](http://jailtime.org) has become [Stacklet](http://stacklet.com/), which may be what you are looking for. Not a lot of virtual appliances, per say, but enough foundations to easily make your own.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Took me a while to respond didn't it? :-)

Comment: @Nick - I really didn't notice :) I just realized you accepted out of curiosity of how the rep recalc effected me here.

Comment: Nah, just wanted to give you some credit - I know how ti works, but I usually hang out over at StackOverflow - hence my low rating here :-)

Comment: @Nick - I'm usually there too. Thanks for the boost though :)